# How can I install IBM Cloud (AKA Bluemix) BX in a Docker using a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, dockerfile

I want to create a Docker to automate some tasks in other docker so I need to install IBM Cloud CLI as explained in https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/download_cli.html#shell_install

How can I do it in a Dockerfile? (Install this:)

```
$ curl -fsSL https://clis.ng.bluemix.net/install/linux | sh
```

So install process is executed automatically and then add the required plugins? (for example:)

```
$ bx plugin install container-registry -r Bluemix
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the final Docker file I am using to extend Jenkins Dockerfile and include Kubectl and Bluemix client (also included Node as we are using Jenkins for it but it can be removed of course):

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
MAINTAINER icordoba@tripbru.com

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN curl  -o /usr/local/bin/kubectl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g jest-cli

RUN curl -fsSL https://clis.ng.bluemix.net/install/linux | sh

RUN bx plugin install container-registry -r Bluemix
RUN bx plugin install container-service -r Bluemix
RUN bx plugin install cloud-functions -r Bluemix
```

(If anyone wants to use it on the fly, I have uploaded to Docker repository as skios/jenkins:lts)